# c++ Cast MyClass* to int*

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I would like to cast a pointer to an instance of `MyClass` to an `int*`, preferably in such a way that I can do this:

```
void function(int*) {...};
MyClass * instance = new MyClass;
function(instance);
```

The int pointer should NOT be a binary copy of the MyClass pointer. Currently, I am using the following code to acheive a similar result:

```
int * MyClass::getIntPointer() {return &my_int;}
```

How do I cast a `MyClass*` to an `int*`?

Comment: I suggest going with `MyClass` -> `int *` if anything, since at least that's actually possible.

Comment: What does `MyClass` contain?

Comment: An int, among other things.

Comment: What are the reasons for doing this?

Comment: It's for an API that I'm writing. Notably the fact that there are a number of function that take in multiple int*s. There are a number of classes that can supply int*s. However some of them only supply one value, so I'd like to be able to put the pointer to the instance of the class straight into the function without having to call any functions on it to get the desired (unambiguous) value.

Comment: How is the function supposed to know whether it's been given an actual pointer-to-int, and when it's been given a pointer-to-class?

Comment: It won't. The MyClass* will be automatically cast to an int* when it's passed into the function, so the function only ever deals with int*s.

Comment: This is why I like to emphasize the distinction between accessing members and casting objects.  You don't want to cast the object.  You want to access the int from the object, and pass that to the function.  That's accessing, not casting.  You can use a custom cast operator to achieve this access, but it's still access.

Comment: Allowing C++ to implicitly cast pointers to other pointer types (except `void*`) would be surprising behavior, and would lead to a lot of potential bugs. I doubt the language will ever be extended to allow this. Further, even this idea violates the "is-a" principle: a `MyClass*` is **not** a `int*` and thus should not be able to substitute for one. If your API expects this feature, *it should be refactored.*

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to access an `int` member of your class?  If so, you can do this:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
  int myInt;
};

void function(int*) {...};
MyClass* instance = new MyClass;
function(&instance->myInt);
```

You don't want to *cast* MyClass to an int, you just want to *access* the member of MyClass.

So here's what that line means:

```
          instance->           // follow the pointer to the actual MyClass object.
          instance->myInt      // access the int, "myInt"
         &instance->myInt      // get the address of that int
function(&instance->myInt);    // call "function", passing to it the address of "myInt"
```

**EDIT**:

If you're creating a class that wraps an int, you can do this with a custom casting operator, as @cmbasnett suggests:

```
class MyClass {
  public:
  int* operator int*() { return &my_int; }
  private:
  int my_int;
};

MyClass instance;
function(instance);  // this line will trigger the custom cast operator.
```

Comment: That's not what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Ok, then please update your question with more info.  Your `getIntPointer` method implied you were operating on a member of your object.

Comment: This is also not completely accurate. Provided `MyClass` complies with the standard definition of a standard-layout-structure, you *can* reinterpret_cast from pointer-to-MyClass to pointer-to-first-member-type. This is supported by C++11 § 9.2,p20.

Comment: Actually, in casting MyClass* to an int*, I am trying to access a member of it. Also, WhozCraig, could you elaborate?

Comment: @WhozCraig, technically yes, but that is a brittle design.  Also, I want to keep the two concepts distinct:  accessing vs. casting.  Conflating the two can confuse new programmers.  It can be useful to create casting operators as accessors in certain circumstances (e.g. wrapper objects), but it's important to understand the distinction.

Comment: @Tim Understandable. I never made claim it was a smart idea; only that the language standard *specifically* calls it out as supported, and with very good reason. (besides paying tribute to C §6.7.2.1/13).

Comment: Is "standard-layout-structure" what they're calling a POD type these days?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe either of these strike your fancy:

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyClass
{
    int myInt;

    operator int*()
    {
        return &myInt;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass* instance = new MyClass();

    //method 1
    instance->myInt = 42;
    int* a = &(instance->myInt);

    //method 2
    int* b = *instance;

    std::cout << *a << std::endl;
    std::cout << *b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I think your method 2 has an extra '*'.

Comment: It de-references the pointer so it can treated as an object, both methods print out 42. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you're stuck. You cannot overload the typecast operator for a *pointer* type. This is the only way you could cast from `MyClass*` directly to `int*` and require the resulting `int*` to point at the first `int` member, even if the class' storage is non-POD.

If you could guarantee that `MyClass` was always a POD type, then `reinterpret_cast<int*>(instance)` would be sufficient. But your demand that "The int pointer should NOT be a binary copy of the MyClass pointer" implies that there is no such guarantee.

If you were willing to start with a `MyClass&` instead of a `MyClass*`, then you could use cmbasnett's example of adding a typecast overload to the class.